# Does static method cache return values?

Tags: java

I have a static method which returns `java.util.Date`. When I first call it, it returns the right date. However, when I call it again after say 2 minutes, it still returns the first date. The date is always created in the method `Date date = new Date();` and is not stored outside of it.

My static method is a part of a rather complicated Android class system, so there is a high likelihood that the error is somewhere else. I just want to know if it is possible that a static method caches its return values.

Comment: No, methods do not cache their return values.

Comment: The likely error is that you're not reassigning the variable you're returning (i.e. a static `Date`), or you're returning a `Date` object created from the same values each time.  Posting your code would go a good way to determine this.

Comment: share your code or else close this question.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. There is a lot of code to go through so I will try to find it myself. I just wanted to know the answer to this simple question. I will accept the answer when I can (after 8 minutes) and I don't know any other way to "close this question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java methods, static or not, never cache the results unless you explicitly do it yourself. In particular, if the method has

```
Date date = new Date();
```

and then produces some computations on the `date`, it will return a result based on the `new Date()` as of the time of the method invocation.

The most likely reason for the return value staying the same is that the method does not get invoked the second time, for example, because the code path leading to the invocation decides that it has a valid value. You can diagnose this by adding a log statement to the static method, and see what happens when your code is supposed to invoke it the second or the third time.